# Use Require.js with an external concatenation tool

Tags: requirejs, yui-compressor

Currently, I use YUI-compressor to concatenate and compress all my JavaScript files. However, for various reasons, I want to start using Require.js.

In development, the files are not concatenated, so I can just use the default `require(filepath)` and `define(modulename)` with Require.js. But how do I handle the fact that in production, YUI will compress all the files, thus invalidating all the filepaths in my `requires`?

Let's say I have one `main.js` which requires `module1.js`. Here's what I want to do:

*Development*

```
require('path-to-module1')... // main.js
define('module1', function()})... // module1.js
```

*Production*

```
require('module1')... // main.js. here though, module1 and main.js are combined.
define('module1')... // yeah, still same file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use and AMD optimizer, for example r.js, to concatenate your files. You can then also use r.js to minify, or you could YUI-comressor to minify .

Read more about r.js optimizer here http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html.

And check out this repo for a good example project for how to use Require.js and how to optimize it https://github.com/volojs/create-template. You can run `node tools/r.js -o tools/build.js` after cloning that repo to see optimizer in action - it will combine all js files in www to a single file.

Finally, you should never name your modules, like

```
define('module1', [], function () {});
```

Always use anonymous modules like so:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {});
```

or

```
define(function (require) { var $ = require("jquery"); });
```

AMD optimizer will use the name your modules for you such that they can all live in one file, but you won't have to worry about that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid a was a bit unclear though. You mention that I can continue to use YUI for compression (I interpret that as concatenation and minification). That's exactly what I want to do, and my question is how to do that.

Comment: For concatenation - you have to use r.js (or another AMD optimizer, but r.js goes best with require.js). For minification - you can use YUI, Closure, Uglify2, etc.

Comment: YUI-compressor doesn't know how to analyse all of the files for the require() calls and find all of the dependencies, etc. So it can't do the concatenation.

Comment: Check out this repo for a good simple example of a Require.js project with the build configured - https://github.com/volojs/create-template